# Match a column against an offline list of strings, then return the first match from the string list

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to build a query that looks through a string column and compares it to a list of strings I have in a text file to see if any of the strings in the list are contained within the text of the string column. I then want to grab the first occurrence of a match and return it.

---

For further context, I have a list of app names in a text file that look like ('app 1', 'app 2', etc). These all belong to one device (let's call that **'device_1'**).

Separately, I have a database table called "**reports**" with a 3 columns:

| report_id | device | report_title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | device_1 | title string 1 |
| 2 | device_1 | title string 2 |
| 3 | device_1 | title string 3 |

I'm filtering the reports table for only **device = 'device_1'**. The "**report_title**" column will hold a long string of text that may or may not contain an app name. Using a sql query, I want to check each report title string to see if it contains one of the app names in my text file, and if so, return that app name for the first match (there SHOULD only ever be one match per title string if there is one).

The final output that I'm trying to get would be something like the below:

| report_id | device | app_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | device_1 | app 1 |
| 2 | device_1 | app 2 |
| 3 | device_1 | app 1 |
| 4 | device_1 | app 3 |

---

I was originally trying to do this somehow by creating a temporary local table to hold the text file strings, but I'm getting error messages when trying to create a table due to not having the appropriate permissions (unless I'm doing it wrong).

Would this be better done by converting the text file into an array somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should do it

```
SELECT TOP (1) report_title
  FROM reports
  WHERE device = 'device_1';
```